# How to find longest continuous duration of data bands in Excel

Tags: excel-formula

I have a list of varying data values between 200 and 1000 collected at 10 minute intervals for 1 year and listed with the date and time. I assess the data in bands of 25, such as 200-225, 225-250.. 975-1000.

How can I find the longest continuous duration count between each band. For example, if the values were 200-225 for 26 hours on 01-mar-2020 through 02-mar-2020 and 2 hours on 15-jun-2020 how would I return the duration of 26 hours (a count of 156)?

| Date | U1 Avg 10m |
| --- | --- |
| 22-Mar-20 00:10:00 | 241 |
| 22-Mar-20 00:20:00 | 248 |
| 22-Mar-20 00:30:00 | 249 |
| 22-Mar-20 00:40:00 | 247 |
| 22-Mar-20 00:50:00 | 246 |
| 22-Mar-20 01:00:00 | 246 |
| 22-Mar-20 01:10:00 | 398 |
| 22-Mar-20 01:20:00 | 557 |
| 22-Mar-20 01:30:00 | 202 |
| 22-Mar-20 01:40:00 | 456 |
| 22-Mar-20 01:50:00 | 249 |
| 22-Mar-20 02:00:00 | 235 |
| 22-Mar-20 02:10:00 | 244 |
| 22-Mar-20 02:20:00 | 565 |
| 22-Mar-20 02:30:00 | 244 |
| 22-Mar-20 02:40:00 | 343 |
| 22-Mar-20 02:50:00 | 233 |
| 22-Mar-20 03:00:00 | 766 |
| 22-Mar-20 03:10:00 | 565 |
| 22-Mar-20 03:20:00 | 877 |
| 22-Mar-20 03:30:00 | 555 |
| 22-Mar-20 03:40:00 | 512 |
| 22-Mar-20 03:50:00 | 800 |
| 22-Mar-20 04:00:00 | 801 |

Expected to fill table below with the longest continuous duration of data that falls in the bands of 25. Example above shows 225-250 occurred 6 times continuously, then 3 times continuously a bit later. I want to return the 6 as it is the longest unbroken stretch of data within that band.

| Range | Longest continuous count |
| --- | --- |
| 200-225 |  |
| 225-250 | 6 |
| 250-275 |  |
| 275-300 |  |
| ... |  |
| 975-1000 |  |

I can determine the count of each band using =COUNTIFS(Table3[U2 Max 10m],">200",Table3[U2 Max 10m],"<225) but I have no idea how to find the longest continuous duration.

Comment: It's good to post data as data, not as a picture. You could post as markdown table using https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables. As for given sample, what do you expect the answer to be?

Comment: Thanks for the link. I edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have Office 365 you could use something like:

```
=MAP(--TEXTBEFORE(D2:D5,"-"),--TEXTAFTER(D2:D5,"-"),
     LAMBDA(start,end,
MAX(
    SCAN(0,B2:B25,
    LAMBDA(x,y,
IF((y>=start)*(y<end),x+1,0))))))
```

[image]